# Pointer char output explanation

Tags: c, pointers

```
   char alpha[] = "abcdefghi";
   char ch[80], *pch = &ch[0];
   strcpy(ch, alpha);
   putchar(*pch++);
   putchar((*pch)++);
   putchar(*++pch);
   putchar(++(*pch));
   printf("\n%s", ch);
```

Why does the putchar function print 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd' respectively? 
Why does printf("\n%s", ch); print acddefghi?
I am really bad with pointer stuff.

Comment: "If you're really bad with pointer stuff", I suggest, seriously, to sit down and get the K&R book, read it, read it, if you still don't get it, debug it, step into it, watch the values of pointers, keep re-reading it, until you will get a lightbulb moment. C thrives on the powers and simplicity of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I will try to explain this as simply as I can.
When you do: putchar(*pch++) what you say is 'print that character of the address that pch points to and then increment the pch to point to the next address'. Essentially, before the first putchar(), *pch = 'a' and after *pch = 'b'(because pch points now to ch[1]).
Now, in the second putchar() what you say is: 'print the character in the address that pch points to and then increment the value of the CHARACTER, in that address, by 1'. So, instead of doing what you did in the second putchar(), you could replace this line whith these two lines:
`putchar(*pch); // 'b'
*pch += 1; // see, you increment the value(notice the *), not the pointer.`
However, because as I said, it increments the character AFTER the second putchar(), it just prints what it was which is 'b'. So, just to clear, after the second putchar(), ch[0] = 'a'(we did not change anything in this value)
and ch[1] = 'c'(we incremented the value of the character by 1 and 'b' + 1 = 'c'). The rest is unchanged, so ch[2] = 'c', ch[3] = 'd' and so on.. but pch points to ch[1]
Now, in the third putchar(), you do something similar with the first except that you first increment the address that pch points and then print the value of this address.So, you could replace the third putchar() with these two lines:
`pch++; // increment the pointer by one, it now points to ch[2], which is 'c'(it remained unchanged)
putchar(*pch); // 'c'`
So, after the third putchar(), ch[0] = 'a'(remained unchanged), ch[1] = 'c'(changed in the second putchar()), ch[2] = 'c'(remained unchanged)
Finally, in the last putchar(), what you do is similar to the second except that you increment the value of the CHARACTER that pch points to before you print it.
Remember that pch points to ch[2] 
So, you could replace the last putchar() with these two lines:

`*pch += 1; // 'c' + 1 = 'd'
 putchar(*pch); // 'd'`

So, after the 4 putchars, ch[0] = 'a'(it remained unchanged), ch[1] = 'c'(changed in the second putchar()), ch[2] = 'd'(changed in the fourth putchar()) and ch[3] = 'd'(it remained unchanged) and the rest of the string remains unchanged, and I think it is now obvious why you get the result you get from printf().

Answer (score 0):

ch is an array of characters.  In C an array is just a pointer to the first element in the array.  That makes ch a pointer to a char (char *) as well.  putchar prints a single character when you pass it a character to print.  *pch++ says 'use the character at this address' then increment the address to point at the next char.   printf prints the whole string because of the format specifier "\n%s" which tells printf to print the array of characters (a string if you will) which is found at the address ch.  Which we know from above is an array of characters.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferences the pointer and returns back the value 'a', then the pointer is incremented by 1.

```
putchar(*pch++);
```

Same as the first explanation above. Returns back 'b'.

```
putchar((*pch)++);
```

Increments the pointer then dereference it, the value returned back is 'c'.

```
putchar(*++pch);
```

Same as the previous, returns back the value of 'd'.

```
putchar(++(*pch));
```

Pointer increments/decrements are based on the type of the variable that is declared.

Since `ch` is declared an array of characters, `printf` prints out the entire contents of that said variable.

```
strcpy(ch, alpha);
```

Copy the contents of `alpha` into an array `ch`, i.e. "abcdefghi"

*All* "arrays" decay into pointers pointing to the first element of type T.
(<sup>They are not really arrays!</sup>)

Answer (score 0):

`*pch++` print current pointer value and increments pointer

`(*pch)++` print current pointer value, and increments that value

`*++pch` It increments pointer and print value of new pointer

`++(*pch)` It increments value of current pointer and then print that new value

```
putchar(*pch++);     // It prints ch[0], print and  increments pointer
putchar((*pch)++);   // It prints ch[1], print and increment value;
putchar(*++pch);     // It prints ch[2], pointer increments and print
putchar(++(*pch));   // It prints ch[2]+1, increment value and print
```

Answer (score 0):

value of address means address location
value of data means the value in that address

Try to think it in this way:
Whatever follows after * is an address.
Eg: *x, here the value of x is an address.
And when you combine * and x i.e. *x, it represents the value at that address.
Whenever you do *p++, the value of p( which is address value) post increments by depending on the data type of the pointer. So, it will point to the next block of address. It won't increment the value of data.

In C, the char pointer points to address of first array and prints the entire array until a null character is received.

Watch lectures on pointer. You will be clear.